# VBA/Macro to add another colum with conditions

Tags: excel, vba, filter, macros, keyword

I need help to write additional column or header named "Person" in Column M with conditions:

If the first column (`Column A`) has these keywords `"AU", "FJ", "NC", "NZ", "SG12"`, The text in (`column M)` should be `Person1`

If the first column (`Column A`) has these keywords `"ID", "PH26", "PH24", "TH", "ZA",` The text in (`column M`) should be `Person2`

If the first column (`Column A`) has these keywords `"JP", "MY", "PH", "SG", "VN"`, The text in (`column M`) should be `Person3`

I want to have this action to be the last thing (after everything).

I tried recording a macro. Filter the keywords and then input manually then slide down to copy but it seems that there should be another way in pasting for the filtered data.

The range should also be dynamic as i will have different amount of data every time

Below is my code so far:

```
Sub person()

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$38").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("AU", _
        "FJ", "NC", "NZ", "SG12"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=1
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Person1"
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested IF formula with OR can accomplish this.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~ you should know what worksheet you are on!
    With Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 12).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=if(or(rc1={""AU"", ""FJ"", ""NC"", ""NZ"", ""SG12""}), ""Person1"", " & _
             "if(or(rc1={""ID"", ""PH26"", ""PH24"", ""TH"", ""ZA""}), ""Person2"", " & _
             "if(or(rc1={""JP"", ""MY"", ""PH"", ""SG"", ""VN""}), ""Person3"", " & _
             "TEXT(,))))"
        'optionally revert the formulas to values
        '.Offset(0, 12) = .Offset(0, 12).value
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code

```
Sub testing()
    last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To last
        If Cells(i, 1) = """AU"", ""FJ"", ""NC"", ""NZ"", ""SG12""," Then
            Cells(i, 13) = "Person1"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = """ID"", ""PH26"", ""PH24"", ""TH"", ""ZA"","  Then
            Cells(i, 13) = "Person2"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = """JP"", ""MY"", ""PH"", ""SG"", ""VN""," Then
            Cells(i, 13) = "Person3"
        [..]
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```